Slow performance on write with data-bound DataGridView
I have a Windows Forms app written in C# which uses 4 data-bound DataGridView (DGV) controls. They consist of text cells and of dropdown value cells. The entire layout (including the data binding) was built using the VS designer.
The content of the DGV views changes dynamically depending on selecting a row in another list view, but the underlying data source is always the same.
When changing values or adding rows, the performance is quite good, also when writing the changed data to the database.
But when closing the Windows Forms app, it can take up to an hour (depending on the amount of data changed) until the form is actually closed, which is quite annoying.
It is difficult to share some piece of code, as I am not sure, what to share exactly. It would help me if you could guide me how to debug this issue.
Any ideas why an application might take so long to close even though data has already been written to the database?
How can I debug the slow performance? Which options are there for performance tuning? Or: which resources could I consult?

You should describe the binding procedure, i.e., you're using typed DataSets, auto-generated by VS, so you have Connection / Command -> Query -> DataAdapter -> (DataSet(s) / Tables / Relations) -> BindingSource / BindingNavigator -> Bound Controls. Or did you setup the whole thing yourself or modified the auto-generated code? -- What kind of database? -- If you're storing the Connection object(s) and/or Command(s), then don't -- You can use the DataAdapter to perform Update() commands upon validation (i.e., after the new data has been validated, you update the database. Same when you delete)

I am using the Designer in Visual Studio. All the objects are auto-created. I am already using Update(). In the meantime I found out, that the values are actually written to the database as soon as they are entered (or after the Upate() method is called), but still the application takes a very long time to close. I don't know what is is doing there or how to debug that, as i am not able to debug the app at this stage using the debugger. (I changed the question accordingly...)
